# How to write a select statement that calls a PL/SQL Function with a "type of table" argument

Tags: sql, plsql

i have a problem. I want to call a function from a select statement, this function has a list of numbers as argument. I know how to call function with "normal" args, but with a type of table. Idk. :/ Thanks for any help.

Here some code. First the type:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE colNumbers IS TABLE OF NUMBER(5,0)
```

The test method:

```
    FUNCTION argLoN(nList in colNumbers) RETURN number
    IS
        nLen number(5,0);
    BEGIN
        return nList.count;
    END argLoN;
```

Comment: It's identical... you just have to ensure that you are actually passing a `colNumbers` type into the function.

Comment: yes, thanks. A co-worker was looking over my code. And I had before the function "argLoN" a second type def (or the first, before i created the global), so the function expected the local type and i used the global. :/
select (packagename.argLoN(colNumbers(1,2,3))) from dual;